# Can docusignapi be used to create entities in netsuite after a doc is signed?

Tags: docusignapi, netsuite

I want to figure out if its possible to have [docusign](https://developers.docusign.com/) call [netsuite](https://www.netsuite.com/portal/home.shtml?noredirect=T) after a document has been signed.
We can pass the parameters docusign needs to pass to netsuite.  So it would save the process a call to netsuite, if docusign can dump some company data into netsuite.

I know there is a plugin for netsuite that works with docusign: ["DocuSign for NetSuite"](https://www.docusign.com/partner/docusign-netsuite).  But this plugin seems to be taking the perspective of calling docusign from netsuite rather than the other way around.

Is there some way to pass data to the docusignapi that is then passed to netsuite in a create entity call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly: You'd need to build the bridge between DocuSign and NetSuite. You could use [DocuSign Connect](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-adding-webhooks-application/) to capture incoming envelope data, and then have your application do the necessary interactions on the NetSuite side.